# Pipelineing & Branch prediction Resources. How to identify how many stalls required. Modify Code

Tags: assembly, mips

I found pipe-lining & branch prediction hard to understand. Are there any recommended resources for these? In particular for MIPS.

- Common questions are like identifying values of control/hazard signals
- identifying number of stalls required
- modify code to reduce stall
- predict if branch is taken

Videos/animation are great to help understand. Otherwise lecture notes or book are fine

Comment: Computer Organization and Design by Patterson & Hennessy covers this. I dunno if it's the best book on the subject though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download WinDLX and run your DLX assembly code in it. DLX ISA is very similar to MIPS ISA and you can quite easily figure out the stalls,forwarding, and all that you need to know .